# Grabbing data on signup through OmniAuth Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

Following [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview), I was able to get a simple authentication system working with Devise and Facebook in my rails app. But for some reason, when a user signs up, i'm able to grab all their info except for their location, bio, website.

Here is what I have in my User model

**User.rb**

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.image = auth.info.image 
    user.location = auth.info.user_location 
    user.about = auth.info.user_about_me 
    user.website = auth.info.user_website


  end
end
```

I already added name, image, location, about, website to my user table in my database.

When a user signs up, location, about, website all return nil. **How do I get these attributes? Am I calling the wrong methods with auth.info.user_location, auth.info.user_location and auth.info.user_website?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly require the permissions of `user_location`, `user_about_me` and `user_website` when configuring Omniauth-Facebook in `config/initializers/devise.rb`, like so:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET",
                scope: 'user_location,user_about_me,user_website'
```

Also you need to checkout the example Auth Hash from the [Omniauth-Facebook gem README](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash) to see how the response is going

For more about the permissions, see  [Facebook Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference) reference page.

Comment: Do I also need to add email, name, and image in there?

Comment: @KatieH the name and picture are accessible by default thanks to the default `public_profile` permission. But yes, you should add `email`.You should checkout [this url](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference) to learn more about permission scopes and what data they make you able to access :)

Comment: Am I calling the right method names? I added the scope thing, but it's still not working.

Comment: @KatieH For location, you should instead write `user.location = auth.info.location`. For about_me, the field is called `bio` and it might be accessible like this: `user.about = auth.extra.raw_info.bio`. If not, you probably should make a new API call to get the `bio` field. The same applies for `website` but the field name is `website` not `user_website`.

Comment: This still isn't working, is it possible that i'm not supposed to add the scope thing in the devise initializer but that I have to make an initializer for omniauth and put the scope thing in there?

Answer (score 0):

The auth hash returns only [this](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash) much of information. Those extra information which you need can be menioned by mentioning in the scope of the configurations in `omniauth.rb`. [see the options in the configurations](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#configuring)